# Why WHMCS shows permission error after applying its security tips even when permission is 777?

Tags: permissions, compiler-errors, whmcs

I've installed WHMCS on my hosting space and did its security tips regarding to [its document](http://docs.whmcs.com/Further_Security_Steps). I've moved templates_c, downloads, and attachments fot one level above public_html (I'm using DirectAdmin control panel) and set their permissions to 777.  After it, I put these lines in **configuration.php** file:

```
$templates_compiledir = "/home/mysite.com/templates_c/";
$attachments_dir = "/home/mysite.com/attachments/";
$downloads_dir = "/home/mysite.com/downloads/";
```

But now, when I want to open WHMCS, I get this error:

> Permissions Error
>   The templates compiling directory '/home/mysite.com/templates_c/' must be writeable (CHMOD 777) before you can continue.
>   If the path shown is incorrect, you can update it in the configuration.php file.

I've tested the below formats for configuration.php file too, but they did not work:

- /domains/mysite.com/templates_c/
- /home/domains/mysite.com/templates_c/

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

level above public_html for DirectAdmin:

```
/home/[USERNAME]/domains/[mysite.com]/
```

insert this code for DirectAdmin in configuration.php file:

```
$templates_compiledir = '/home/[USERNAME]/domains/[mysite.com]/templates_c/';
$attachments_dir = '/home/[USERNAME]/domains/[mysite.com]/attachments/';
$downloads_dir = '/home/[USERNAME]/domains/[mysite.com]/downloads/';
```

Answer (score -1):

I searched and searched all over for an answer on this and finally figured it out. At least in my server environment for WHMCS (Rackspace Cloud Sites) you need to enter the absolute path to the file, not the relative path to the file as is demonstrated in the WHCMS example.